# Excel formula disappears when saving as .xls

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2011

I have a long formula in one of my cells. It is:

```
=IF(K11=1,MATCH(C66,valv1,-1),IF(K11=2,MATCH(C66,valv2,-1),IF(K11=3,MATCH(C66,valv3,-1),IF(K11=4,MATCH(C66,valv4,-1),IF(K11=5,MATCH(C66,valv5,-1),IF(K11=6,MATCH(C66,valv6,-1),IF(K11=7,MATCH(C66,valv7,-1),IF(K11=8,MATCH(C66,valv8,-1),IF(K11=9,MATCH(C66,valv9,-1),IF(K11=10,MATCH(C66,valv10,-1),IF(K11=11,MATCH(C66,valv11,-1),IF(K11=12,MATCH(C66,valv12,-1),"ERROR"))))))))))))
```

The formula may produce the value "6" for example.

The formula works fine, but when I close my spreadsheet and open it again, the number "6" still shows in the cell, but when I look at the formula bar at the top, the long formula has been replaced with "=#VALUE!" (and hence the cell no longer functions). This happens when I don't change a thing; I just close and open again.

I have played around, and found that this only happens when I save as .XLS and not .XLSX, so it seems like some kind of bug.

However, I can't save as .XLSX because it says "Cannot store VBA or Excel 4.0 macro sheets" - but I have some VBA that I need to work on the sheet.

Why can I not use VBA with .XLSX? Or.. why does the formula screw up when I save as .XLS? Is there an alternative to these two formats?

I am using Excel 2011 for Mac by the way.

Thank you!

Comment: There is more than one question here, one related to why the formula doesn't work and one related to the format the file is saved. This can cause confusion for answer being for one or the other. Please break this into two questions.

Answer (score 1):

I have found some answers:

An .XLS file adheres to the limitations of Excel 2003, one of which is that it won't allow more than 7 nested IF functions.

If I save as an .XLSM or .XLSB file, the macros work.